# GWT - Make CellTable Cell use HTML?

Tags: html, gwt, cell

I have a CellTable where I want to put HTML-code in the cells.
The following code is not working, the blank spaces are removed from the output.

```
    TextColumn<MyCell> column1 = new TextColumn<MyCell>()
    {
        @Override
        public String getValue(MyCell myCell)
        {
            String result = "     " +myCell.getValue();
            return result;
        }
    };
    table.addColumn(column1 , "Header1");
```

I know this could be done using css but I just want to know how to put HTML-code in the cells. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

AFAIK additional whitespace is ignored in HTML - you should use pre tag to maintain formatting.Anyway please find my column sample below. It generates nice progress bar from values contained in objects backed by data provider.

```
final SafeHtmlCell progressCell = new SafeHtmlCell();

    Column<UiScheduledTask, SafeHtml> progressCol = new Column<UiScheduledTask, SafeHtml>(
            progressCell) {

        @Override
        public SafeHtml getValue(UiScheduledTask value) {
            SafeHtmlBuilder sb = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
            float percent = new Float(value.getCompleted())
                    / new Float(value.getAll());
            int rounded = Math.round(percent * 100);
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div style='width: 100px; height: 20px; position: relative;'>");
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div style='z-index: 2; display: inline; width: 100px; position: absolute; left: 0px, top: 0px; text-align: center;'>"
                    + value.getCompleted()
                    + "/"
                    + value.getAll()
                    + "</div>");
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div style='position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100px; z-index: 1'><div style='display: inline; float: left; width: "
                    + rounded
                    + "%; height: 20px; background-color: #82cd80;'></div>");
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div style='display: inline; float: right; width: "
                    + (100 - rounded)
                    + "%; height: 20px; background-color: #c54c4d;'></div></div>");
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("</div>");
            return sb.toSafeHtml();
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks jgrabowski! This works perfect! And yes, additional whitespace is ignored in html unless you use the pre tag.