# use cellTree with widget

Tags: gwt

I want to add customized widgets into the cell tree, something like below:

```
>Label1
 customized-widget
>Label2
 customized-widget
>Label3
 customized-widget
```

Under each label, there is a customized widget(extends composite)

I tried to use

```
public void render(
        com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context, Customizedwidget value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        if(value!=null) sb.appendEscaped(value.getElement().getInnerHTML());                            
}
```

but, sb.appendEscaped(value.getElement().getInnerHTML()) is not working, it shows me a bunch of html or maybe javascript code when I click label.

I would like to know how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SafeHtmlCell to include your own html content inside of the cell table's cell,

```
SafeHtmlCell html = new SafeHtmlCell();
  final Column<DTO, SafeHtml> htmlContent = new Column<DTO, SafeHtml>(html) {
      @Override
      public SafeHtml getValue(DTO object) {
        // code goes here
    return new SafeHtml;
      }
    };

dataGrid.addColumn(htmlContent, "");
```

or you can use ButtonCell(to insert buttons), check other cell's also.

check this: [GWT - Make CellTable Cell use HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801985/gwt-make-celltable-cell-use-html)